# How do I give parameters to a function in a javascript file that accesses HTML and CSS attributes?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to pass html parameters to a function in a javascript file, I tried it like this:

```
function func(element, value) {
    element.getElementById('myelement').InnerHTML = value;
}
```

and then something like this:

```
<button type="button"
onclick="script.js.func(document, 'example')">Click Me!</button>

<p id="myelement"></p>
```

But it doesn't work. I'm fairly new to JavaScript so sorry if I'm not as good.
I know that script.js.*anything* probably wouldn't work, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using the HTML `onclick` attribute, you can use JavaScript Event Listeners:

```js
var button = document.getElementById("mybutton");
var paragraph = document.getElementById("myelement");

function func(value) {
  paragraph.innerHTML = value;
}

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  func("incredible value here");
});
```

```html
<button id="mybutton">Click me!</button>
<p id="myelement"></p>
```

If you need to specify the parameters in the HTML itself, you can specify them with a `data-` attribute:

```js
var button = document.getElementById("mybutton");
var paragraph = document.getElementById("myelement");

function func(value) {
  paragraph.innerHTML = value;
}

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var value = button.getAttribute("data-value");
  func(value);
});
```

```html
<button id="mybutton" data-value="some value">Click me!</button>
<p id="myelement"></p>
```

Comment: note: I used simpler syntax because OP is beginner, usually one would use arrow functions or `const` instead of `var`

Answer (score 0):

If the JavaScript file is included in the head of your HTML, you *should* be able to just call it like this:

```
<button type="button"
onclick="func('Testing')">Click Me!</button>

<p id="myelement"></p>
```

Now, as far as passing parameters into the call, you can pass things like strings, numbers, etc no problem. If you want to pass in the "document", as in your example, I would actually recommend to do that inside the JavaScript function, instead of passing it in.

```
function func(value) {
    document.getElementById('myelement').InnerHTML = value;
}
```

And your HTML:

```
<button type="button"
onclick="func('Testing')">Click Me!</button>

<p id="myelement"></p>
```

In your case, using vanilla JS, I think this can resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are trying to do with this code

```
<button type="button" onclick="script.js.func(document, 'example')">Click Me!</button>
```

You are trying to `load` the `script.js` file and then the function inside it which is `func`.

For that in JavaScript you have to load the file first and then you can use the JavaScript functions. Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>  <!-- Assuming the js file is on same level as the index.html file -->

<button type="button" onclick="func(document, 'example')">Click Me!</button>
```

On a fundamental level, this should work. If you want to refactor or clean your code have a look at other answers.